# Is there an accepted way of either running a thread or executing sequentially?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

Due to reasons outside my control, I have to write code to perform the following action:

- If a condition is met, execute the function on a separate thread and wait for it to finish later in the code.
- Otherwise, execute the program sequentially by simply calling the function without using a new thread.

```cpp
boost::thread thread;
if (condition)
{
    thread = boost::thread(function);
}
else
{
    function();
}
<some more code here>
thread.join();
```

Is there a better way of doing this than the above code?

Unfortunately, I am quite restricted with what solutions I can use but any advice/idea/opinion is welcome.

Comment: Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future

Comment: Your code example needs to say `if (thread.joinable())` before `thread.join();` or it will throw an exception when `!condition` because you can't join a default-constructed thread.

Comment: See my edit @Jonathan Wakely. The thread object is default constructed as such before the _if-else_ case. According to the boost documentation, this should create a _Not-a-Thread_ object, and if `join()` is called on such an object, it should return immediately. Although, I agree that even in this case, adding the `if (thread,joinable()) call makes things clearer.

Comment: Ah, apparently the `boost::thread::join()` behaviour depends on whether the `BOOST_THREAD_THROW_IF_PRECONDITION_NOT_SATISFIED` macro is defined. For `std::thread::join()` it's always an error to try and join a non-joinable thread. For `boost::thread` it is configurable.

Answer (score 3):

A future that is either built ready or running an async task.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative, `std::future` might help, something like:

```
std::future<void> fut;
if (condition)
{
    fut = std::async(std::launch::async, function);
}
else
{
    fut = std::async(std::launch::deferred, function);
    fut.wait();
}
// some more code here
fut.wait()
```

Comment: Would this be the same as calling `thread = boost::thread(function)` then add `thread.join()` right after immediately in the `else` case?

Comment: async with `std::launch::deferred` runs in thread, when it is waited on

Comment: No, `thread.join()` blocks the calling thread waiting on the created thread

Comment: Isn't that what `fut.wait()` does as well? According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait) it "Blocks until the result becomes available."

Comment: This confusion is why I think Caleth's answer is better, because it avoids `async` in the sequential case, making it more obvious what happens. If you don't want to defer the execution it's odd to use `async(launch::deferred, ...)`; just run the function instead.

Comment: Right, so when you wrote "in thread" you meant that is runs **in** the calling thread and not in a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Another take on using futures

```
std::future<void> fut;
if (condition)
{
    fut = std::async(std::launch::async, function);
}
else
{
    function();
    std::promise<void> prom;
    fut = prom.get_future();
    prom.set_value();
  // or std::experimental::make_ready_future() if avaliable
}
// some more code here
fut.wait()
```